# JPA Inheritance issue

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, jpa

Working with JPA 1 (hibernate-core version 3.3.0.SP1 and hibernate-entitymanager version 3.4.0.GA) :
I've some entities similar to those defined below, where ChildOne and ChildTwo extends from the Father entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_FATHER")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.INTEGER, name = Father.C_ID_CTG)
public class Father {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "sq")
@Column(name = "ID_PK", nullable = false)
@BusinessId
private Long id;
...
} 

@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_CHILD_ONE")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorValue(Categories.ID_CTG_ONE)
public class ChildOne extends Father {
    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_CHILD_TWO")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorValue(Categories.ID_CTG_TWO)
public class ChildTwo extends Element {
    ...
}
```

Let's say I've one entity having a Father element, and another having a collection of father elements. In both cases, should go the children entities.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_ONE")
public class OneTable {

@JoinColumn(name = "ID_PK", referencedColumnName = "ID_PK", nullable = false)
@ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Father element; 
    ...
} 

@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_ANOTHER")
public class Another  {

@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "id", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Collection<Father> elementCollection;

    ...
}
```

I'm expecting to obtain always the children elements but when I get the element `getElement()` returns the father element 
and, on the other hand, when I get the collection `getElementCollection()` the children elements are coming.

Apparently, the `@JoinColumn` is the cause of this behaviour, doing the join with the father table and forgetting the children elements.
The collection is working as expected.

How could I get the children element with a `getElement()` call? Any ideas or workarround? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not caused by `@JoinColumn`. 
The reason is Lazy Loading. 
I manage to pinpoint your problem in simpler example. 
Forgive me for changing convention from Father to Parent.

In the example below, uninitialized Element is type of `jpa.inheritance.issue.Parent_$$_javassist_1`. It is a Hibernate Proxy - dynamically created subclass of Parent. 
You can "unproxy" it by invoking Hibernate proprietary API `getHibernateLazyInitializer().getImplementation()`.

Collection of `elementCollection` is also Lazy Initialized. The type of the collection is `org.hibernate.collection.PersistentBag` which is being initilized with correct data at the time of first access. 
Collection is initialized all at once.
Please see the test which successfully passed green with your exact version of Hibernate (3.3.0.SP1/3.4.0.GA).

```
    @Test
    public void test() {
        Child c = new Child();
        em.persist(c);

        Another a = new Another();
        a.setElement(c);
        Collection<Parent> col = new ArrayList<Parent>();
        col.add(c);
        a.setElementCollection(col);
        em.persist(a);
        c.setAnother(a);

        long idx = a.getId();
        tx.commit();

        // I'm cleaning the cache to be sure that call to a.getElement() will return proxy.
        em.clear();
        tx = em.getTransaction();
        tx.begin();

        a = em.find(Another.class, idx);
        Assert.assertNotNull(a);
        Parent p = a.getElement();
        // At this point p is a type of jpa.inheritance.issue.Parent_$$_javassist_1

        Assert.assertTrue(p instanceof Parent);
        Assert.assertFalse(p instanceof Child);

        // At this point a.elements is a not initialized (empty) collection of type org.hibernate.collection.PersistentBag
        // When we access this collection for the first time, records are read from the database 
        Assert.assertEquals(1, a.getElementCollection().size());

        if (p instanceof HibernateProxy) {
            p =
                    (Parent) ((HibernateProxy) p).getHibernateLazyInitializer()
                            .getImplementation();
        }

        // At this point p is a type of jpa.inheritance.issue.Child
        Assert.assertTrue(p instanceof Child);
    }

    @Entity
    public class Another {

        @JoinColumn(name = "element_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
        @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
        private Parent element; 
        public Parent getElement() {
            return element;
        }

        public void setElement(Parent element) {
            this.element = element;
        }

        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "another", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        public Collection<Parent> elements;

        public Collection<Parent> getElementCollection() {
            return elements;
        }

        public void setElementCollection(Collection<Parent> elementCollection) {
            this.elements = elementCollection;
        }

        // @Id ...
    }

    @Entity
    @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
    public class Parent {
        @ManyToOne
        private Another another;

        public Another getAnother() {
            return another;
        }

        public void setAnother(Another another) {
            this.another = another;
        }

        // @Id ...
    }

    @Entity
    public class Child extends Parent {         
    }
```

You don't need `@DiscriminatorColumn` nor `@DiscriminatorValue` because those annotations are needed with `InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE` as an only resort to determine the type. 
With `InheritanceType.JOINED` Hibernate is able to determine polymorphic type by checking if there is a record in both (Parent and Child) tables with the same Id.
You can turn on hibernate logging to see how the query to determine the type looks like. It works like this:

```
select
    another0_.id as id0_1_,
    another0_.element_id as element2_0_1_,
    parent1_.id as id1_0_,
    parent1_1_.name as name2_0_,
    case
        when parent1_1_.id is not null then 1
        when parent1_.id is not null then 0
        else -1
    end as clazz_0_
from
    Another another0_
inner join
    Parent parent1_
        on another0_.element_id=parent1_.id
left outer join
    Child parent1_1_
        on parent1_.id=parent1_1_.id
where
    another0_.id=?
```

Comment: Just a few notes about your answer... As far as I know the spec does not require an implementation to use discriminator columns to implement JOINED inheritance, however, the assumption is that if @DiscriminatorColumn is specified then it would be used...
On the other hand, eventhough your solution actually works, still have some doubts. Knowing that the lazyness returns proxies, why the ManyToOne returning a proxy to the parent (jpa.inheritance.issue.Parent_$$_javassist_1), and the OneToMany collection children proxies (jpa.inheritance.issue.ChildOne_$$_javassist_1) ???

Comment: The exact return type of `getElement()` call in real world application is not deterministic. Cause if the object is found in 1st or 2nd level cache it will typeof `Child`. That's why I call `em.clean()` in the middle - to pinpoint the specific behaviour. This is why it's best to be type agnostic in situation with Parent-Child hierarchy. if you really need a correct type you can "unproxy" as I proposed or better change FetchType to EAGER (as "unproxying" load the relationship anyway).

Comment: About ManyToOne I will post some info in the near future.

Comment: Quite interesting your comments! Thanks a lot for your time!
But that's another thing that I'm not pretty sure... I've already tried to change the FetchType to Eager (that was my first option) but still had the same behaviour (meaning, having a collection with eager fetching, still returns proxy elements the same way)

em.clean()? I guess you meant em.clear()... I've considered that too, but it didn't work for my particular case (but I know it could be an option)

Comment: Yes, `em.clear()`. But it's not enough.  Just to have my test pass reliably I had to turn off 2nd level cache, clear EntityManager and restart transaction... And I wouldn't recommend it in production. Are you sure you have to be dependent on the exact type? Maybe its time to redesign?

Comment: Well, I've no option about the exact types, but deproxy seems to work perfectly fine to me. Thanks again...

Comment: No problem, we are using unproxying in our project too.